# Compiling a contract via web3 creates a possibly random key

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js

In a node terminal I'm accessing my private net via web3. When compiling the contents of the contract I get a random key `/var/folders/1_/fbr644kx6nq4bj81q_1_vzlc0000gn/T/geth-compile-solidity525074877:Voting` :

```
{ '/var/folders/1_/fbr644kx6nq4bj81q_1_vzlc0000gn/T/geth-compile-solidity525074877:Voting':
   { code: '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',
     info:
      { source: 'pragma solidity ^0.4.6;\n// We have to specify what version of compiler this code will compile with\n\ncontract Voting {\n  /* mapping field below is equivalent to an associative array or hash.\n  The key of the mapping is candidate name stored as type bytes32 and value is\n  an unsigned integer to store the vote count\n  */\n  \n  mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public votesReceived;\n  \n  /* Solidity doesn\'t let you pass in an array of strings in the constructor (yet).\n  We will use an array of bytes32 instead to store the list of candidates\n  */\n  \n  bytes32[] public candidateList;\n\n  /* This is the constructor which will be called once when you\n  deploy the contract to the blockchain. When we deploy the contract,\n  we will pass an array of candidates who will be contesting in the election\n  */\n  function Voting(bytes32[] candidateNames) {\n    candidateList = candidateNames;\n  }\n\n  // This function returns the total votes a candidate has received so far\n  function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) returns (uint8) {\n    if (validCandidate(candidate) == false) throw;\n    return votesReceived[candidate];\n  }\n\n  // This function increments the vote count for the specified candidate. This\n  // is equivalent to casting a vote\n  function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate) {\n    if (validCandidate(candidate) == false) throw;\n    votesReceived[candidate] += 1;\n  }\n\n  function validCandidate(bytes32 candidate) returns (bool) {\n    for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++) {\n      if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {\n        return true;\n      }\n    }\n    return false;\n  }\n}',
        language: 'Solidity',
        languageVersion: '0.4.11',
        compilerVersion: '0.4.11',
        compilerOptions: '--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize',
        abiDefinition: [Object],
        userDoc: [Object],
        developerDoc: [Object] } } }
```

Should the compiled JSON not start with simple the key `code` ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is the name, including absolute filename, of your contract. (See the ':Voting' at the end of that key.) It appears geth creates a temporary file to invoke solc, which is why that filename would have apparently random text in it.

If this is a problem, you can use solc externally, thus giving it a deterministic filename. Otherwise, you can also simply use that second JSON object (the one pointed to by that key.)